# Amazon S3 bucket - download only certain files

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with 10,000 images sitting in it with a standard naming convention:

```
001_small.jpg
001_large.jpg
002_small.jpg
002_large.jpg
```

Since there is such a large amount of files I don't want to download ALL of them and I don't want to sit there for a couple of hours to select just the `*_large.jpg` files...

Can someone suggest an S3 file manager that can let me select only the *_large.jpg files to download?

Answer (score 1):

Mac? Transmit or web based http://www.s3fm.com/